# socket.io - emit to socketid(single client) not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am using version 0.9.4 (I can use any version as per your guidance)

in server (app.js), I am storing socket id like this:

```
var socket_ids = [];
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket_ids.push(socket.id); #This is how I am getting socket id. My real code logic is totally different, but getting socket id using socket.id;
    socket.on('createNote', function(data) {
        socket.broadcast.to(socket_ids[0]).emit('onNoteCreated', data);
    });
});
```

In short, I have 4 people opened sessions, all 4 are different users.

When p1 sends message, it should reach p2 only.
When p3 sends message, it should reach p4 only.

Keeping the if..else logics aside(I am fine with that), when I am broadcasting message using socket id, the client/browser with that socket id is not receiving that message. Also, above above broadcast line of code(other lines are custom for SO) not giving errors but client not receiving.

But these clients/browsers receiving messages when broadcasted to everything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest socket.io version, this is how I would do it:

```
var sockets = [];

io.on("connection", function(socket){

    // Store whole socket object.
    // NOTE: You should probably loop through sockets array
    // to see if a socket with this id already exists
    sockets.push(socket);

    socket.on("createNote", function(data){
        sockets[0].emit("onNoteCreated", data);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I guess its 1.4.5. Let me test it and get back. Thanks.